# How do I make a VB.NET application that can rip websites from Google?

Tags: vb.net, url

I'm trying to make a VB.NET application that can take some text in (via Text Box) and then search that text in Google, and take the resulting URLs from Google.

So my questions are:

How do I make it search Google?

How do I make it take the found URLs from Google?

And any ideas represented through code would be appreciated, I know I some how have to rip the URLs from google, but how?

Comment: Why you need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the Google search engine but have everything located inside your application.  In this case, Google provides an API that will allow you to do this without doing web scraping or other hacks.  You can read more about it and see examples (in .NET but usually C#) here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/

Here is an example of how to do this in your code:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mem_1910/1st08162006033511AM/1st.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of a n00b when it comes to programming. How exactly do I integrate that into my program? Do I have to download something? What code would I have to add?

Comment: @Jacob - No problem.  I posted an example that should walk you through it.  The only issue will be that the code is in C#, but you can either translate it yourself or use a translator like this one:  http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: :-)  Glad I could be of help.